# Change alignment for individual table rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Is it possible to change alignment for individual rows? Example:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| Left       |    Center    |        Right |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the alignment of individual cells, and not entire rows?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `\multicolumn` command with `1` as first argument. You may also define a new command (say, `\myalign`) as a shortcut.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\myalign}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rll}
(right-aligned) & (left-aligned) & (left-aligned) \\
foo & foo & foo \\
foo & foo & foo \\
\myalign{l}{foo} & \myalign{c}{foo} & \myalign{r}{foo} \\
foo & foo & foo 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I find it convenient to use `\let\mc\multicolumn` and to use it like `\mc1l{foo}` and `\mc1c{foo}` because single-character arguments don't need braces.

Comment: This solution seems a little inconvenient in case of long rows with many columns or when e.g. half of the table rows should have a different alignment. I would welcome a solution in which one command would change alignment of all the following table rows. Something like this: `\newtabularalignment{rrcll}`.