# How to right align columns but center align header row using pgfplotstable?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

I am a newbie with `pgfplotstable`: I would like to right align the columns of the table containing my data, but keep the headers center-aligned. Here is the code for the tables - does anyone know how to modify it to accomplish this?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Stuff}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=comma,
string type,
every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
display columns/0/.style={column name=Years, column type = {r}},
display columns/1/.style={column name = Data1, column type = {r}},
display columns/2/.style={column name = Data2, column type = {r}}
]{./DataOutput/Resids/Stuff.csv}
\end{table}
```

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get different alignments in some cells of a `tabular`, you can wrap the cells in a `\multicolumn` (see [Change alignment for individual table rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/change-alignment-for-individual-table-rows)). PGFPlotstable provides a key for doing this automatically for the header row using the key `multicolumn names`, which takes an optional argument for the alignment. `multicolumn names=l` would left-align the header, for instance. The default is `c`, which centers the text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Stuff}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=comma,
string type,
every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
display columns/0/.style={column name = Years, column type = {r}},
display columns/1/.style={column name = Data1, column type = {r}},
display columns/2/.style={column name = Data2, column type = {r}},
multicolumn names
]{
A, B, C
DDDDD, EEEEEEE, FFFFFFF
GGGG, HH, III
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough and helpful answer.

Comment: Pleasure! Please consider upvoting the answer by clicking the triangle next to it. If you consider your problem solved, you can also click the tick mark.

Comment: If a column is formated via `dec sep align`, the `multicolumn names` assignment does not have any effect. Maybe you know a solution for fixing this?

Comment: Great answer. Newbie comment in passing, instead of ``display columns/0/.style=`` I was able to get the same effect with ``columns/myColumnName/.append style = {column type = {r}}``, where I refer to the column by its name rather than the index.